# EINVAL when calling semget() under Linux

Tags: c++, linux, ipc, semaphore

Why can't i open semget with 4 semaphores for its semaphore set? 
ie.:

```
semget(key_t key, int nsems, int semflg);
```

calling the above function with nsms as 3 is fine, but with 4 it returns minus 1..

```
int sempahore = semget((key_t)key,4,IPC_CREAT | MY_PERMS);
```

The above code only works if i change 4 for 3

other wise errno returns invalid arguments

Comment: Can you add the real code you're trying to execute, and the value of errno after the failed call?  Because errno will indicate the error that occurred and 9/10 there's a relation between  the parameters you're using and the error.

Comment: I did, thanks, please read it now :C

Answer (score 3):

According to the man page on my Linux box, `semget` can return `EINVAL` if "nsems is less than 0 or greater than the limit on the number of semaphores per semaphore set (SEMMSL), or a semaphore set corresponding to key already exists, and nsems is larger than the number of semaphores in that set."

I suspect you're hitting the second case - check whether you've already created a set with the same key and 3 semaphores in its set.

Comment: It might be interesting to note that [ipcs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ipcs) can be used to investigate the existing semaphore sets and [ipcrm](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ipcrm) can be used to manually remove them.